# How to select GID in /etc/password through Regular expression?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, vim

[image: Please see this picture first!]

I want to select the `GID` field in `/etc/passwd`.

I use `/:[0-9]\{1,\}` to select `UID`, but I don't know how to select `GID`.

Comment: Could you tell me how to solve it? not formatting.

Comment: You can try to parse the beginning of the line: `^[^:]\+:\(\d\+\):\(\d\+\):` and then use the capture groups.

Answer (score 2):

GID is the fourth field so you could get it with:

```
/\([^:]\+:\)\{3}\zs[^:]\+
 ***************###""""""

* matches the first three fields
# starts the actual match from here
" matches 1 or more non-colons
```

[image: result]